# Windows Azure imports in Android; results in an error

Tags: android, azure, import, cloud, azure-mobile-services

I have followed this tutorial about Windows Azure mobile services using Android:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-data/

but I always get the error "**the import com.microsoft cannot be resolved"** for the import lines such as: "import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient" ,.. etc

Consequently, all the following related code added to the project contains errors.

I added the required files to the "*libs* " folder, and I am connected to the internet and refreshed the project...

I cannot figure out why the imports fail.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow your IDE is not using the libraries.  Are you using Eclipse?

If so, in Eclipse, right click on the project, go to Properties, choose Java Build Path, and then Order and Export.  Make sure the box next to "Android Private Libraries" is checked.

Comment: The last sentence is incomplete.

Anyway,
Yes, I'm using Eclipse.

And the "Android Private Libraries" is checked. Are there further changes to make in the "Order and Export" tab?

Comment: There shouldn't be.  What files do you have in the libs folder?

Comment: I have the folders of  Mobile Services Android SDK downloaded from here:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=280126&clcid=0x409

besides android-support-v4  and  gson-2.2.2

Comment: You'll definitely need the gson library as the Mobile Services SDK relies up on it.

Comment: It is working now; The ".jar" files were distributed inside folders. They were not seen by the project (as you said). When I placed the files directly in the "libs" folder (without subfolders), the import is now working. 
Thank you.

Comment: (but there should be no duplicates)
The "Feedback" sample here is a ready working example. For anyone trying, observe the files in the "libs" folder here:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/android-samples/
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following is missing from your build.gradle file.

```
dependencies { 
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.2+'
}
```

For info on the latest sdk version, you can visit :- 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/CHANGELOG.android.md